# Dismiss Alert Programmatically Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I need a little help with a UIAlert. I get an error `"UIAlertController can only have one action with a style of UIAlertActionStyleCancel"`. I know it is because I am initiating this alert outside of the function, but unsure how to fix it. How can I get access to the alert within the if `blah < 80 {` conditional?

```
let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Blah", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
@IBAction func blahButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {        

        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Do Something", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            // I have code here
        }))

        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Do Something 2", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            // I have code here
        }))

        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            // I have code here
        }))

        presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Later in the code I get values via Bluetooth and need to dismiss the Alert if a value is below 80.

```
if blah < 80 {
alertView.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Any chance that `blahButtonPressed` is being executed more than once?  The error message sounds like you're adding "Cancel" too many times.

Comment: No. Its just a button. that I only press once and not calling anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% but does it work when you only press the button once? If so, then it may be because you are adding the actions to your `alertView` inside the `@IBAction`. Instead, you may want to try moving the addition of the `UIAlertAction`'s outside of the `@IBAction` and only presenting the alert view inside of it. Like so:

```
let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Blah", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Do Something", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        // I have code here
    }))

alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Do Something 2", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        // I have code here
    }))

alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        // I have code here
    }))

@IBAction func blahButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
  presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This way the `UIAlertAction`'s don't get added every single time the "blahButton" is pressed (which would result in more than one `UIAlertAction` with style of "UIAlertActionStyleCancel")

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed it if anyone comes accross this.

```
var newAlert: AnyObject?


@IBAction func blahButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {        
    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Blah", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Do Something", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        // I have code here
    }))

    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Do Something 2", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        // I have code here
    }))

    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        // I have code here
    }))

   newAlert = alertView

        presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

// When I need to close. If blah is below 80

```
if blah < 80 {
    if let newAlertView = newAlert as? UIAlertController {
       newAlertView.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```